# URL rewrite from www.example.com/subdirectory to example.com/subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a solution for the following problem:

I use a CMS and want the backend to only be available at `http://example.com/backend` and not at `http://www.example.com/backend`. The rest of the site should be available at `www.example.com`.

How do I change my *.htaccess* file to achieve this? I already have a rewrite rule from (non-www) to www.

Here's what I currently have in my *.htaccess* file:

```
  ##
  # Uncomment the following lines to add "www." to the domain:
  #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  #
  # Uncomment the following lines to remove "www." from the domain:
  #
  #   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  #   RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  #
  # Make sure to replace "example.com" with your domain name.
  ##
```

So, the first bit is the redirect from non-www to www. It works on the domain part of the URL. As explained, I need a rewrite rule from the backend login at `http://www.example.com/backend` to `http://example.com/backend`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a specific directory that you want to be accessed without `www` while everything else would be accessed with it.

You will need both rewrite rules (one of which you currently have commented out) and you will need to add some extra conditions to each:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(backend.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^/backend$` - The `$` (end of string anchor) should be removed from the end of the _CondPattern_ in order to match all URLs that just start "/backend". In the case of the 2nd (backend) redirect, you can include the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` pattern instead of having a separate condition - marginally more efficient. ie. `RewriteRule ^(backend.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`.